# Trying to cut a Spotify link with regex using dart

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I am trying to cut a Spotify playlist link into getting all the chars between / & ?, however I am getting nowhere with regex.

The link: `https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DX60OAKjsWlA2?si=2NBcsO0bQS-CQclS1rNoCA`
What I want: `37i9dQZF1DX60OAKjsWlA2`

My code so far looks the following, but I am getting nothing out of it:

```
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(
      "\w*\?",
      caseSensitive: false,
      multiLine: false,
    );
```

When I print with

```
print("stringMatch : " +
        regExp
            .stringMatch(
                "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/7x1ebdezDivH4mXAhUdR2S?si=TxHdzuvnTzuoCD5TFR4z_g")
            .toString());
```

It just prints an empty String. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Use `r"\w+(?=\?)"`. See https://regex101.com/r/I1n15a/1.

Comment: Almost works with r"\w*\?". However here I am getting the `?`, which I do not want. How do I exclude it instead of including it? Thanks for the fast answers.

Comment: Use https://regex101.com/r/I1n15a/1, `r"\w+(?=\?)"`

Comment: I did not know about that webpage. Thanks for the answers, it's working now @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Don't roll your own regex, use the built-in URI parser. https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/Uri/parse.html. After parsing, the URL parameters are available in the `queryParameters` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match 1+ word chars, or chars other than `/`, up to a question mark excluding it.

Note that you need to double escape bacslashes in a regular string literal, or single ones in as raw string literal.

In your current case, you may use

```
r"\w+(?=\?)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I1n15a/1/)

Or,

```
r"[^?/]+(?=\?)"
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I1n15a/2). Here, `[^?/]+` matches 1+ chars other than `?` and `/`.

A non-regex way is to split on `?`, get the first item, then get the chunk of chars after the last `/`:

```
String s = "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/7x1ebdezDivH4mXAhUdR2S?si=TxHdzuvnTzuoCD5TFR4z_g";
String t=s.split("?")[0];
print(t.substring(t.lastIndexOf("/")+1));
```

Output: `7x1ebdezDivH4mXAhUdR2S`